# when i clicked button then Value will for Set Increment on each click- Android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I try this code.but it increment only once .It should be work on onlick setIncrement ?

```
Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    try {


                        String recino=receipt.getText().toString();
                        String lamn=lastRecAmt.getText().toString();
                        String lRecNo=lastRecno.getText().toString();

                           long recNoLong=Long.valueOf(recino);
                          long recNoInc=recNoLong+1;
                          receipt.setText(recNoInc+"");


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: please tell us the logic you want to implement to increment this variable.(like either it must increment on some button click or some kind of event that must increment it or something else)

Comment: You'll need to post more code. This doesn't tell us enough to help you.

Comment: with the help of all ans...  my problem is solved....thanks :)

Comment: Plz vote up on my question :)

Comment: thanks..to all of u !! put block of my question     this is really wrong.If u guys are really good .so please give me also time learn this     @ Raghunandan,@ Arash,@ Ilya

Comment: @nobalG i am not able to ask ques...?  what i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  String str = edttext.getText().toString.trim();
  int i = Integer.PareseInt(str)+1;
  edttext.setText(i);
```

Comment: hello @Blue Green   from my this question.now onwards i am not  able to post or ask question. what  i do ?

Answer (score 3):

First initialization is fine, next time on you should get value from editbox for recNoLong and then increment and populate to edittext.
from second loop on you should do as below

```
recNoLong=Long.valueOf(receipt.getText().toString());
recNoInc=recNoLong+1;
receipt.setText(recNoInc+"");
```

Comment: please vote up on question...i am not able to post or ask question. what i do ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
 @Override          
 public void onClick(View v) 
 {   
     recNoLong=Long.valueOf(receipt.getText().toString());           
     receipt.setText("" + recNoInc++);           
  }         
});
```

Comment: Sir please vote up my question.  i am not able to post or ask question. what i do ?

Comment: @17Coder If you want to post new question try to get more reputations by answering to new questions and get up votes. And try to post the question with clear explanation and related code and errors if any. For More info http://stackoverflow.com/help/

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided sufficient code. Based on what you have, I think you have not updated `recino` to contain the latest receipt no. Try adding this before the first line of code

```
recino = receipt.getText().toString();
```